# What are the crashes caused by the Google WebView glitch?

Tags: android-webview

[Google's WebView is reported to cause a lot of app crashes](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-confirms-webview-issue-crashing-android-apps/).  Could anyone shed some light on the type of crashes caused by this glitch so that we can ignore them (i.e. not blame our apps).
Looking at crash reports of Google Play Console, I suspect the following crashes are in this category:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000034529dc  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-fmgcNAbKmGQjSaUydZ05_w==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x2d3000)


 backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000034529dc  /data/app/com.android.chrome-Yv1VfYaotWfuAadCJoYaHg==/base.apk (offset 0xa0f000)


  backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000002919eba  /data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk (offset 0xb09000)
```